# np.isnan for array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have an array which I want to change into an array of True and False values to I can remove nan values.

When trying this using np.isnan as follows it's fine:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.,2.,np.nan])

a
Out[4]: array([ 1.,  2., nan])

np.isnan(a)
Out[5]: array([False, False,  True])
```

But when I try to do the same on my array, it doesn't work:

```
a
Out[9]: 
array([73788400000.0, 80017300000.0, 83680400000.0, 84939700000.0,
       83877800000.0, 83911700000.0, 85368100000.0, 83808200000.0,
       85936400000.0, 85177800000.0, 82705400000.0, 82119100000.0,
       73935400.0, 64018400.0, 42796500.0, 43130000.0, 42637600.0,
       167911000.0, nan], dtype=object)
np.isnan(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-f4b5b5e7f347>", line 1, in <module>
    np.isnan(a)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I suspect, given the error, this has something to do with the object type but I'm not sure how exactly.

Please note, when trying math.isnan, it only appears to take single values:

```
math.isnan(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-6d4d8c26d370>", line 1, in <module>
    math.isnan(a)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you make use of pandas, and use `isnull()`? It checks for "NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays"

Comment: That worked but the solution below requires less switching between pandas and numpy arrays but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your array to `float` and this will work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([73788400000.0, 80017300000.0, 83680400000.0, 84939700000.0,
              83877800000.0, 83911700000.0, 85368100000.0, 83808200000.0,
              85936400000.0, 85177800000.0, 82705400000.0, 82119100000.0,
              73935400.0, 64018400.0, 42796500.0, 43130000.0, 42637600.0,
              167911000.0, np.nan], dtype=object)

res = np.isnan(a.astype(float))

# [False False False False False False False False False False False False
#  False False False False False False  True]
```